# How to skip the missing XML data column values while selecting form select query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xml-parsing, cross-apply, for-xml-path

My query returns:

> Msg 9421, XML parsing: illegal name character error

I need to skip the rows where there is no data in the below table

```
SELECT
    ps.person_num,
    q1.r1.value(‘.’,’varchar(50)') as id,
    q2.r2.value(‘.’,'varchar(50)’)) as name
FROM
    persons ps
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT CAST(SELECT CAST(sd.data AS xml)) AS p1(p1))
CROSS APPLY
    p1.p1.nodes(‘/person_data/person_id’) q1(r1)
CROSS APPLY
    p1.p1.nodes(‘/person_data/person_name’) q2(r2)
```

`Persons` table has two columns:

```
      Person_num    data (text column)
         1          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <person_data>
                   <person_id>52<person_id/> <person_name>varna</person_name> </person_data >

         2         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?>?</?>

         3         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <person_data > <person_id>53<person_id/> 
                    <person_name>mala</person_name></ person_data >

         4         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> < person_data > <person_id>54<person_id/> 
                   <person_name>nayan</person_name> </person_data >

         5         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?>?</?>

         6         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> < person_data > <person_id>55<person_id/>
                   <person_name>tara</person_name></person_data >

         7         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> < person_data > <person_id>56<person_id/> 
                   <person_name>janu</person_name> </person_data >
```

Comment: BY no data do you mean the column contains `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?>?</?>`? I encourage you to add your sample data as DDL+DML so others can copy and paste out to play with.

Comment: If so `where data != '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?>?</?>'` would seem to solve.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: I strongly suggest you store XML in a column with type `xml`. Not sure why you need `.nodes` here, `.value` with a path will suffice. And `/somenode/text()` is faster than just `/somenode`

Comment: SQL Server doesn't not appreciate `encoding="UTF-8"`, or any encoding attribute really, in XML declarations/processing instructions. You could try removing that before `cast(sd.data as xml)`.